# Mixing the usage of static, extern and inline keywords between definition and declaration

Tags: c

```
inline void t1();
void t1(){}        // t1 is still inline?

void t2();
inline void t2(){} // t2 is inline?

static void t3(){}
inline void t3(); // t3 is still static?

inline void t4();
static void t4(){} // t4 is still inline?
                   // "inline function 't4' declared but never defined", are these not the same function?

extern void t5();
inline void t5(){} // t5 is still extern?

inline void t6(){}
extern void t6(); // t6 is still inline?

int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

Please note in the above snippet some functions are first *fully defined* and their prototype is changed afterwords with a different storage type, or inlined.

I have the following questions:

1- Are the storage types, or the `inline` state of the functions persistent as per comments?

2- Why compiler warns that `t4` is declared but never defined? isn't `static void t4(){}` the definition?

Comment: Note that, in C, your `func()` definitions and declarations are incomplete (the empty parentheses declare a function with an *unspecified* number of arguments). Use `func(void)` to be more accurate. And your `t4` definition (as `static`) conflicts with the previous declaration (`extern` is default).

Comment: @AdrianMole So why wouldn't the compiler complain about it? if I remove `inline` it says `static declaration of 't4' follows non-static declaration`, why is `inline` changing the behaviour?

Comment: Clang-cl gives a warning: *warning : redeclaring non-static 't4' as static is a Microsoft extension [-Wmicrosoft-redeclare-static]*. Maybe you should enable all compiler warnings.

Comment: @AdrianMole: The declarations are without prototypes, not incomplete. “Incomplete” is a description of object types for which there is insufficient information to know the size. And a function definition necessarily specifies the parameters it has—if it does not have a prototype, it has a declaration list. If that declaration list is empty, it means the function has no parameters.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @AdrianMole Next version of C (C23?) may change a function declaration of `xxx foo();` to mean `xxx foo(void);`.  We'll see.

Comment: @AdrianMole IIRC K&R was pretty loose with `xxx foo();`. I thought it was like `xxx foo(...);` which did allow `arg` processing then (not today).  IAC, in those wild west days (1973 - 1989), there were competing compiler implementations, each doing their own "right" way.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica tentative definitions are for variables tho, we have functions here.

Comment: @Dan fair enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C 2018 6.7.4 7 says:

> … For a function with external linkage, the following restrictions apply: … If all of the file scope declarations for a function in a translation unit include the `inline` function specifier without `extern`, then the definition in that translation unit is an *inline definition*.

6.9 5 says:

> An *external definition* is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function (other than an inline definition) or an object.

For each of your cases except `t3`, the identifier appears with external linkage and it is not true that all of the file scope declarations include `inline`. Therefore, there are no inline definitions for those cases.

> `inline void t1();
> void t1(){}        // t1 is still inline?`

There is no inline definition, per above.

> `void t2();
> inline void t2(){} // t2 is inline?`

There is no inline definition, per above.

> `static void t3(){}
> inline void t3(); // t3 is still static?`

C 2018 6.2.2 5 says:

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`…

Therefore, for `inline void t3();`, we may read `extern inline void t3();`. Then 6.2.2 4 says:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier extern in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration…

Therefore, the linkage of `t3` in `extern inline void t3();` is the same as in the prior declaration `static void t3(){}`, so it is internal.

> `inline void t4();
> static void t4(){} // t4 is still inline?
> // "inline function 't4' declared but never defined", are these not the same function?`

Per above, there is no inline definition of `t4`.

Further, `inline void t4();` declares `t4` with external linkage, and `static void t4(){}` declares it with internal linkage, and 6.2.2 7 says:

> If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

> `extern void t5();
> inline void t5(){} // t5 is still extern?`

Yes, per 6.2.2 5, above.

> `inline void t6(){}
> extern void t6(); // t6 is still inline?`

There is no inline definition, per above. This case is equivalent to `fahr` in example 1 in C 2018 6.7.4 10, where the commentary explicitly says that the definition of the function is an external definition.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. So are your references saying `if declaration has inline, then the definition is also inline, even if it doesn't include the "inline" keyword`? which makes t2 and t3 inline?

Comment: @Dan: No. The C standard says, for an external identifier, if not **all** declarations have `inline`, then **none** of them is an inline definition.

Comment: Ok, in that case the declaration of `t1` does have inline `inline void t1();`, why isn't its definition inline then?

Comment: @Dan: Because not **all** declarations of `t1` have `inline`.

Comment: But that's the only declaration, isn't `void t1(){} ` a definition?

Comment: @Dan: Definitions are declarations.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you are referring to. I always thought `void test();` is a declaration and `void test(){}` is the definition. I also can't understand what this sentence means `An external definition is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function...`?is it specific to externs? googling didn't help.

Comment: @Dan: Every definition is a declaration. Some declarations are definitions and some are not. `extern int x;` is a declaration that is not a  definition. `int x = 3;` is a declaration that is a definition. The grammar for declarations is specified in clause 6.7 of the C 2018 standard, and definitions fit in that grammar.

Comment: @Dan: In the sentence “An external definition is an external declaration that is also a definition of a function”, an “external declaration” is one that is outside of any function. If the declaration includes a function body (statements and declarations inside `{ }`, then it is a definition. So, if a declaration is outside of any function and has a function body, it is an external definition. Googling is not a good way to learn programming languages. Reading textbooks and the C standard is better.

Comment: Thank you, does the `Every definition is a declaration` rule apply to variables too? I have read books about C but these are details that are related to the design of the language, it's like reading a car manual before driving it, not many do it until the time comes.

Comment: Could I also confirm then, by the above rule, every function body is an `external definition` ?

Comment: @Dan: Yes, variables are included. A function body is just part of an external definition; with the rest of the function declaration, it is an external definition. (Note that this is just for “normal” strictly conforming C code. GCC has an extension that allows defining functions inside functions, and that would not be covered clearly by the C standard.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235198/discussion-between-dan-and-eric-postpischil).

Comment: One more thing to confirm (hopefully the last one), it is common practice to just fully define inline functions in a header correct? I haven't seen much places which declare and later define inlines.

Comment: @Dan: Defining inline functions in headers is a reasonable practice for various things, such as defining some convenience function that does not need to hide implementation information.

Comment: Need to bug yo for one more question, would you know if `Every definition is a declaration` rule also applies to C++?

Comment: @Dan: I expect so, but I am not into the C++ standard to the same degree as I am the C standard. C++ 2017 draft n4659 6.1 2 says “A declaration is a *definition* unless…,” so I would think the set of definitions is a subset of the set of declarations.